# Why isn't the "2" in the normal distribution a parameter?

Tags: normal-distribution

$$f(x)=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi \sigma^2}} e^{-\dfrac{(x-\mu)^2}{2 \sigma^2}}$$

The normal distribution has parameters $\mu\in\mathbb{R}$ and $\sigma\in \mathbb{R}_+$ as above, and regardless of their values, the function integrates to $1$ over $\mathbb{R}$. However, if instead of the above function we write
$$f(x)=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{a\pi \sigma^2}} e^{-\dfrac{(x-\mu)^2}{a \sigma^2}}$$

with $2$ replaced by a new parameter $a$, it still integrates to one, and is a valid distribution. Why is this never used? If you add a new parameter, doesn't it make it easier to find parameters to "fit" the data better rather than with just $2$ parameters, since this new parameter allows for a more flexible distribution?

Comment: Why the downvote, please?

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted +1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we introduce this new parameter, firstly it is redundant (it can be absorbed in $\sigma^2$) and secondly it means that $\sigma^2$ is no longer the variance of the distribution in general. It is the variance exactly when $a=2$, which is why the constant is set to this value.

Edit: I forgot to make it explicit that no, this does not give extra "freedom" of the function, exactly because it can be absorbed in the $\sigma^2$ parameter.

Comment: I see...so what I just did by introducing this new parameter $a$ is just change the variance to $a\sigma^2/2$, thus giving no new information to the distribution. Thanks

Comment: @DylanZammit Indeed. My main point is that the normal distribution p.d.f. is not just some arbitrary function to be tweaked to fit data. It is in fact a very special distribution with many nice properties, which is the reason it is used so frequently, the main property probably being its appearance in the central limit theorem.